# CodeIgniter Pretty Debugging Output

Tags: php, debugging, codeigniter, frameworks

Basically what I want to do is be able to set a switch somewhere: `$debugging_mode = 0 or 1`  that will allow me to attach a nicely formatted output to the bottom of my views.

I have written a library with a lot going on and I have some output like this:

```
echo var_dump(array_before_operation);

// do some operations 

echo var_dump(array_after_opertion); 

// do some more stuff 

echo "We have exactly 3 matches!";
```

**My question is what is the cleanest way to get pretty debugging output?** ( I am aware of CI's profiler, but I still need something extra )

Where is a good place to set a global debugging mode? I know zend framework has a development or production setting in the .htaccess file, but I don't see that in CI

Should I use PHP's native output buffer to collect my debugging stuff? then how could I append that to the view?

Thanks for your ideas ladies and gents!

Answer (score -4, accepted):

global debugging mode: use config class http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html

cleanest way to get pretty debugging output: text file

Comment: I don't even see define('ENVIRONMENT', x) anymore in the index.php, i wonder if that changed that in CI 2.0 and they didn't update the manual accordingly ?

Comment: correcting my own comment. Its brand new as of 2.0.1, i'm still on 2.0.0

Comment: you do not need to define use config.ini

Comment: this is a pretty broad answer.  there is no reference to any sort of debug settings for code igniter through that link.

Comment: This is a non-answer. Give some details about what to do with the config for debuging.

Comment: it should be comment , add some details please